# set cookie on page to show bootstrap popup once a day

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm learning JavaScript and I see that this question has been asked many times, but I can't get this to work for me. 
What I want to do is, show a bootstrap modal once a day.

What I have so far is:

```
function setCookie(cookiename, cookievalue, expdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime()+(expdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = cookiename + "=" + cookievalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cookiename) {
  var name = cookiename + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
     var c = ca[i].trim();
  if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
}


//I want to check if there is a cookie.
//if I have not set a cookie, I want to show my modal, 
//if there is a cookie then return;
//The cookie should expire in one day. 
function checkCookie() {
   var showed = getCookie("showed");
   if (showed != null && showed != "") {
      var date = new Date(showed).getDate();
      var currentDate = new Date().getDate();

      if (currentDate > date) {
          return true;
      }
       return false;
   }
    return true;
}
```

Now, if I change the last return true; to return false; my modal does not show up. 
The way it is now I see the modal every time. 
What am I doing wrong?
How can I fix this?

Comment: can you post the way you set cookie?

Comment: I set cookie in my function setCookie

Comment: yes, but what is the instruction?
because I tested your code and all seem work good. I don't think you have a date problem!

Comment: Yes I see the cookie being set correctly, the issue is when I check to see if there is a cookie, in my checkCookie(); There is no cookie and my modal shows up. I need to be able to check if there is a cookie and then if there is a cookie I don't want to show my modal.

Comment: uhm, ok. Now my mission today is complete this task!:)
has the cookie that you see the name "showed"? what browser are you using (name and version)?

Comment: now i'm getting a checkCookie() not defined error. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: lets move this to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135300/discussion-between-newdev-and-misterwolf).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setCookie(cookiename, cookievalue, expdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime()+(expdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = cookiename + "=" + cookievalue + "; " + expires;
}

    function getCookie(cookiename) {
  var name = cookiename + "=";
  var startPos = document.cookie.indexOf(name);
  if(startPos == -1) return null;
  startPos+=(name.length);
  if(document.cookie.indexOf(";",startPos) == -1){
    return document.cookie.substring(startPos,document.cookie.length);
  }
  else{
    return document.cookie.substring(startPos,document.cookie.indexOf(';',startPos));
  }
return null;
}


//I want to check if there is a cookie.
//if I have not set a cookie, I want to show my modal, 
//if there is a cookie then return;
//The cookie should expire in one day. 
function checkCookie() {
   var showed = getCookie("showed");
   if (showed != null && showed != "") {
      var date = new Date(showed).getDate();
      var currentDate = new Date().getDate();

      if (currentDate > date) {
          return true;
      }
       return false;
   }
    return true;
}
```

Also when setting cookie,
use

```
setCookie('showed',new Date().toGMTString(),1);
```

because we are using the value of cookie, not the expire time of cookie to check. So the value must be a datestring

Comment: Edited getCookie. Check it now

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with getting or setting a cookie. I just need to be able to check if there is a cookie.